# pass pug input element content to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to insert, delete, and update data on a data base with html buttons. To do this i am using a pug page that is called by node express, and it all works fine. Until i try to insert data into my database. so i have this in my pug file

```
script(src='editor.js')
...
p Item Type *required*<br/>
input(type="text", id="iType", name="iType")
p Item name *required*<br/>
input(type="text", id="name", name="Name")
p Item price *optional*<br/>
input(type="text", id="price", name="Price")
p Item ABV *optional*<br/>
input(type="text", id="desc", name="ABV")
p Item description *optional*<br/>
input(type="text", id="desc", name="Desc")

button(id="addItemBtn" onclick="updateMenuItem("+document.getElementById('iType').value+","+document.getElementById('name').value+","+document.getElementById('Price').value+","+document.getElementById('ABV').value+","+document.getElementById('Desc').value+")") add
```

and with it i am trying to pass the contents of the input element to my javaScript function in editor.js

```
function updateMenuItem (itype,name,price,abv,desc) {
    //set up connection variables for the sql query
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlconfig);
    var sqlreq = new sql.Request(conn);

    //initiate the connection
    conn.connect(function (err) {
        //throw an error if the page cannot connect to the server
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        //
        sqlreq.query("insert into food '"+itype+"','"+name+"','"+price+"','"+abv+"','"+desc+"'"), function () {
            console.log('OK')
        };
    })
};
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be:

```
button(id="addItemBtn" onclick="updateMenuItem(document.getElementById('iType').value, document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('Price').value, document.getElementById('ABV').value, document.getElementById('Desc').value)") add
```